# Why is DOMDocument::load("local file") throwing an error from getaddrinfo?

Tags: php

I've just set up a new computer (Ubuntu 14.04), and installed all the same libraries and packages I had on my old computer. For all intents and purposes, the new system is the same OS and software as what my old computer, 3 other developers, and our build/test/productions systems are using. We are all running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9

I made a checkout of the codebase we are working on, but when I run the code on my new computer, I get an error that has not happened on any of the other machines.

```
DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

When I get the error context (by capturing the error through a customer handler), the filepath is:

```
/var/local/file/path/that/exists
```

And I can open that file from the command line.

Why can't DOMDocument::load() and why is it trying to resolve a network address?

---

For completion - the XML file does refer to DTD at `http://dtd.local.domain/custom.dtd` - but when I use `dns_get_record()` that address does resolve, and the dtd file is available on at the location, so it doesn't look like that's the issue.

Comment: Are you sure the apache user has the right to read said file?

Comment: all the relevant files are 644

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not answer (yet).
Could you please put

```
libxml_set_external_entity_loader(
    function ($public, $system, $context) {
        echo 'external_entity=', var_export( array($public, $system), true ), ";\r\n";
        return $system;
    }
);
```

into your script so it gets executed before the DOMDocument::load() and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32642931/edit) the output you get to your question text?

Comment: As soon as I saw the output, I realised there was still a document where the DTD URL wasn't using the FQDN - this was the first computer I've tried setting up without DNS search domains for our local domain